# Variance under Inheritance scala

Tags: scala

If trait Function2 signature is

```
trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef
```

why cannot I create a function like this

```
  val f2 : (String, String) => Int = new Function2[String, String, Int] {
    def apply(s1 : String, s2 : String) = s1.length + s2.length
  }
```

and use it like this

```
  val listOfFullNames : List[(Any, Any)] = List(("Mark","Smith"), ("Kim","Hughes"), ("Zoe","Zaldana"), ("Matt","Damon"))

  val output3 = listOfFullNames.map(x => f2(x._1, x._2))
```

Answer (score 3):

The contravariance in the first two type-parameter means that `Function2[Any,Any,Int]` is a subtype of `Function2[String,String,Int]`, because any function that maps two `Any` values to an `Int` can also be applied to two `String` values and therefore can also be considered as a function `(String,String) => Int`.

Comment: Because you are trying to replace a subtype by a supertype which doesn’t work